# Transferring DownValues

Tags: symbolic, assignment, built-in-symbols

I have a code in which I define something like this:

```
cc[1, 2] = 1;
cc[2, 6] = 12;
cc[3, 7] = 3;
```

After some manipulation I define a sort of temporary variable related to `cc`:

```
cctemp[1, 2] = 13;
cctemp[2, 6] = 8;
cctemp[3, 7] = 4;
cctemp[1, 9] = 87;
```

There are new and old indices.

Now in my code i wanna replace `cc` with `cctemp`.
I can do the trivial assignment and i can use a `Do` for the substitution but its not the best. How could I realize the assignment ?

(Ps maybe something like `Activate @ Inactive` ....)

Thank you

Comment: (1) `List` is in the title, but it looks like you are assigning `DownValues` rather than making `cc` a list. Do you mean `cc[[1, 2]]` rather than `cc[1, 2]`, etc.? (2) Why can't you just do `cc[1, 2] = cctemp[1, 2]` (or `cc[[1,2]] = cctemp[[1, 2]]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DownValues[cc] = DownValues[cctemp] /. cctemp -> cc;

cc @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {1, 9}}
```

> {13, 8, 4, 87}

If `cc` has some assignments that are not overridden by the assignments in `cctemp` you can use

```
DownValues[cc] =  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   Join[DownValues[cctemp], DownValues[cc]] /. cctemp -> cc, #[[1,1]]&]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of the undocumented `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` function that underlies the Wolfram Cloud. Suppose:

```
cctemp[1,2] = 13;
cctemp[2,6] = 8;
cctemp[3,7] = 4;
cctemp[1,9] = 87;
```

Then:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[cc] = Language`ExtendedDefinition[cctemp] /. cctemp -> cc;
```

Finally:

```
DownValues[cc]
```

> {HoldPattern[cc[1, 2]] :> 13, HoldPattern[cc[1, 9]] :> 87, 
>    HoldPattern[cc[2, 6]] :> 8, HoldPattern[cc[3, 7]] :> 4}

Comment: ok thank you for the answer; just two things because i want to learn: 1) where can i find the package of this function       2) why should i prefer this way over the answer of kglr ?

Comment: @siderius There is no package, the function is built-in. Using ``Language`ExtendedDefinition`` transfers UpValues, DownValues, FormatValues, etc. If all you care about are DownValues, then using DownValues instead is better.